# How to use flask-login with mysql database

Tags: mysql, flask

Hello I have been trying to use `flask-login` to manage my flask app which use `mysql` as its database.
I want to restrict users to login first before logging out and accessing the home page like:

```
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user
@auth.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    flash('Your are logged out! Welcome again! ', category='success')
    session.pop('loggedin', None)
    session.pop('user_id', None)
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
```

But i fail on how to make a logged in user be able to access the home page or how to make the `login_required` as false for logged in users. This means I cant figure out how to use `login_user` and `LoginManager`. I know how to use `flask-login` incase of `flask-sqlalchemy`. But i cant use it in case of `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wanna do that. Anyways, you can use the following code:

For the first question, with flask-login you can do:

```
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(request.url)
```

for the second question you can use flask-sqlalchemy as orm for mysql.

Comment: Thanks but to use current_user , It is required that my database table to be in form of a python class. But i can't because i am using mysql database. The solution you provided works with sqlite but i am using MYSQL as my database.

Comment: You can user Sqlachemy with MySql the same way with sqlite.